# Playframework 1.3 : How to mock repeated fields in FunctinalTest?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using `Play 1.3` and my `Role` model looks like this:

```
class Role{
  // blabla
  public String name;
  @OneToMany(mappedby="role")
  public List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And here's my controller's action:

```
public static void save(Role role) {
  role.save()
  ok();
}
```

Now I need to write a functional test case on it:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("role.name", "new role abc");
// TODO : I need to add multiple resources here   <<<----- Problem here
response = POST("/roles/save", params);
// blabla
```

Is there anyway to solve this problem in play ? I only need to send repeated "resources.id" to controller(It works in a real browser's form), but `POST()` only accept `Map<String,String>` here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section on [HTTP to Java binding](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/controllers#binding) that should help you out here:

> [**POJO object binding**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/controllers#binding)
>
> Play also automatically binds any of your model classes using the same simple naming convention rules.
>
> ```
> public static void create(Client client ) {
>     client.save();
>     show(client);
> }
> ```
>
> A query string to create a client using this action would look like:
>
> ```
> ?client.name=Zenexity&client.email=contact@zenexity.fr
> ```
>
> Play creates a Client instance and resolves HTTP parameter names to properties on the
>   Client object. Unresolved parameters are safely ignored. Type mismatches are also safely ignored.
>
> In order to update a list of model objects, use array notation and reference the object’s ID. For example imagine the Client model has a list of Customer models declared as List Customer customers. To update the list of Customers you would provide a query string like the following:
>
> ```
> ?client.customers[0].id=123
> &client.customers[1].id=456
> &client.customers[2].id=789
> ```

So I'd say something like this should solve your problem:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("role.name", "new role abc");
params.put("role.resources[0].id", "1");
params.put("role.resources[1].id", "10"); // etc.
response = POST("/roles/save", params);
// blabla
```